# Difference between List<T> and IEnumerable<T> in method signature

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee: Person
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { FirstName  = "John", LastName = "Doe", Position = "Missed"}
        };

DoSomesing(employees);
```

It works fine if the signature of the method DoSomesing is:

```
public void DoSomesing(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
```

But it does not work if the signature of the method DoSomesing is:

```
public void DoSomesing(List<Person> persons)
```

Why it works in first case?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, `List<T>` is not.

Comment: You should read about [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Comment: I think we need little more information on the error. Im guessing you are using VS. Are you able to declare the signature that uses the List? Or it is causing an exception at run time?

Comment: covariance vs contravariance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) which means `IEnumerable<Employee>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<Person>` since `Employee` is a subtype of `Person`. In contrast, `List<T>` invariant so `List<Employee>` is not a subtype of `List<Person>`.

Comment: I wouldn't say that `IEnumerable<Employee>` is a **subtype** of `IEnumerable<Person>`. It's not. It's just that the reference is implicitly castable.

Comment: @Enigmativity - It is a subtype, covariance preserves the direction of the subtyping relation, contravariance reverses it.

Comment: I don't think that's the case: `typeof(IEnumerable<Person>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<Employee>)) == true` but `typeof(List<Employee>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable<Person>)) == false`.